# Using an SQL LEFT JOIN with the MAX() and MIN() functions

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's assume I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE logins (
    user_id NOT NULL,
    day DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id, `day`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

What I'm trying to do here is get a query for all users with the first day they logged in and the last day they logged in. The query I was executing to achieve this looks like the following:

```
SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS name, MIN(l.day) AS first_login, 
    MAX(l.day) AS last_login
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN logins l ON u.id = l.user_id
```

The problem is that because of the use of `MIN()` and `MAX()`, I'm only receiving one row back in the entire result. I'm sure it's my use of those functions that's causing this. I should have one row per user, even if they do not have any login entries. This is the reason for me using a `LEFT JOIN` vs an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to use aggregate functions (min, max, ...) you need grouping. Try something like this:

```
SELECT u.id AS id, u.name AS name, MIN(l.day) AS first_login, MAX(l.day) AS last_login
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN logins l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Any sensible database except MySQL would have given you an error on mixing row-terms and aggregate terms, making the error clearer. MySQL, unfortunately allows this behavior, making it harder to notice that you forgot the `group by` clause needed to generate a row per user:

```
SELECT    u.id AS id, 
          u.name AS name, 
          MIN(l.day) AS first_login, 
          MAX(l.day) AS last_login
FROM      users u 
LEFT JOIN logins l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY  u.id, u.name -- missing in the original query
```

Answer (score 2):

Grouping is a waste of resources.
Use nested select statement instead.
eg.

```sql
SELECT 
  u.id AS id, 
  u.name AS name,
  (
    SELECT MAX(logins.day) FROM logins WHERE logins.user_id=u.id
  ) AS last_login 
FROM users u;
```

Answer (score 0):

MIN and MAX are aggregate functions.

You should use `GROUP BY` with some field from `u`, like `id`.